# Time complexity of nested for loop with inner iteration variable dependent on the outer one

Tags: algorithm, loops, for-loop, time-complexity

This is the loop structure :

```
for (int i = 1 ; i < n ; i++) {
    for (int j = 0 ; j < n ; j += i) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

My guess was `O(nlogn)` as it clearly cannot be `O(n^2)` since the increment in `j` is increasing and it clearly cannot be `O(n sqrt(n))` since the increment is not that high. But I have no idea how to prove it formally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each time complexity of the inner loop is based on the value of `i` is `n/i`. Hence, total time would be `n + n/2 + n/3 + ... + n/n = n(1+1/2+1/3+...+1/n)`.
As we know `1+1/2+1/3+...+1/n` is a harmonic sereis and asymptotically is `log(n)`. Hence, the algorithm is run in `O(nlog(n))`.